# groupby + apply results in a series appearing both in index and column - how to prevent it?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a following data frame:

```
dict1 = {'id': {0: 11, 1: 12, 2: 13, 3: 14, 4: 15, 5: 16, 6: 19, 7: 18, 8: 17},
 'var1': {0: 20.272108843537413,
  1: 21.088435374149658,
  2: 20.68027210884354,
  3: 23.945578231292515,
  4: 22.857142857142854,
  5: 21.496598639455787,
  6: 39.18367346938776,
  7: 36.46258503401361,
  8: 34.965986394557824},
 'var2': {0: 27.731092436974773,
  1: 43.907563025210074,
  2: 55.67226890756303,
  3: 62.81512605042017,
  4: 71.63865546218487,
  5: 83.40336134453781,
  6: 43.48739495798319,
  7: 59.243697478991606,
  8: 67.22689075630252},
 'var3': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2}}
ex = pd.DataFrame(dict1).set_index('id')
```

I wanted to sort with within groups according to `var1`, so I wrote the following:

```
ex.groupby('var3').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('var1'))
```

However, it results in a data frame which has `var3` both in index and in column. How to prevent that and leave it only in a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add optional param to groupby `as_index=False`

```
ex.groupby('var3', as_index=False) \
  .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('var1'))
```

Or, if you don't want multiIndex

```
ex.groupby('var3', as_index=False) \
  .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('var1')) \
  .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Comment: this is not correct, this create a multiindex... `MultiIndex([(0, 11),(0, 13),(0, 12),(0, 16),(0, 15),(0, 14), (1, 17, (1, 18), (1, 19)],names=[None, 'id'])`

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? Op asks only about var3

Comment: I don't think OP wants multiindex, it just wants to order

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
df_sorted=ex.groupby('var3').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('var1')).reset_index(drop='var3')
print(df_sorted)

        var1       var2  var3
0  20.272109  27.731092     1
1  20.680272  55.672269     1
2  21.088435  43.907563     1
3  21.496599  83.403361     1
4  22.857143  71.638655     1
5  23.945578  62.815126     1
6  34.965986  67.226891     2
7  36.462585  59.243697     2
8  39.183673  43.487395     2
```

**But you only need [DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) 
sorting first by `var3` and then by `var1`:**

```
df_sort=ex.sort_values(['var3','var1'])
print(df_sort)

         var1       var2  var3
id                            
11  20.272109  27.731092     1
13  20.680272  55.672269     1
12  21.088435  43.907563     1
16  21.496599  83.403361     1
15  22.857143  71.638655     1
14  23.945578  62.815126     1
17  34.965986  67.226891     2
18  36.462585  59.243697     2
19  39.183673  43.487395     2
```